# Silence gdb "switching to thread" output messages

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, gdb

I am currently debugging a multi-threaded application in Linux using gdb.  I'm getting a lot of noise in the output and am wondering if there is anything I can do to silence it.
I'm getting a lot of these: "[Switching to Thread ~~ (LWP ~~)]"
I have used the 'set print thread-events off', but that only seems to catch the start/stop of the thread.
Does anyone know of a way that I can get gdb to stop showing these Switching thread messages?

Answer (score 2):

I use gdb version 10.

`set print thread-events off`

Works for me. Links to the [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads.html).

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know of a way that I can get gdb to stop showing these Switching thread messages?

There is no good way at present.

If you're desperate, one idea would be to write wrappers for commands like `continue` that work by redirecting output to `/dev/null` (and then undoing the redirection somewhere, like in a stop hook).  This will cause you to miss any other gdb output as well though.

It's worth filing a gdb bug report about this.